# Reg Exp to check for constant string in variable line

Tags: regex

I use reg exp about every 9 months or so, so I'm very rusty.

I have a string that contains a constant string within it

e.g.

```
xxxHELLOxxx   

xxHELLOxxx

HELLOxxxx
```

where the constant string HELLO can be at any position and x can be anything.
Also HELLO could be lower case as well

How do I check for HELLO ?
Simple i know but I can't think this morning

Comment: Most languages have a method that test whether a string contains a substring. I would use that one. If you need a regular expression however, it would literally be `HELLO`. It couldn't be simpler.

Comment: Then you must have done something wrong. It works perfectly fine: https://regex101.com/r/tG2aA0/1 (might want to set the case-insensitive match flag though).

Comment: Also works fine with `12HELLO111(123)` :https://regex101.com/r/bD4vI7/1

Comment: Yes sorry, only giving partial example the string is 12HELLO111(123)  tested with \d{2}/HELLO/\\d{3}({1}\\d{3}){1} fails

Comment: Well, why are using such a complicated (and incorrect) expression if you simply want to test for `HELLO`?

Comment: yes, it's a rubbish reg exp, but it comes from some software that generates the reg exp given a pattern e.g. 11AAAAA(111) where A = any upper case alpha and 1 is any digit ( and ) are taken as is. Problem being is the new insertion of the constants string in this case HELLO

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex :

```
/.*hello.*/i
```

Note that don't forget to use flag `i` for ignoring case!

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aP4bO7/1)

Also as @Felix Kling said in comment you don't need regex for such task, based on the language you are using you can use a proper operand to check the member ship of a sub-string within a string!

For example in python you can use `in` operand :

```
if `HELLO` in main_string:
     #do stuff
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `\b` here? What makes you think the OP wants a case-insensitive match?

Comment: Ok, what's the purpose of the `.*` now?

Comment: @FelixKling *Also HELLO could be lower case as well*

Comment: @FelixKling What you mean? it should be any thing!But I'm agree with your comment on OP's question! there is no need to use regex in this task.

Comment: Ah, missed the lower case part. My point is that `.*` at the beginning or end of the expression is unnecessary (depends on the programming language of course, but in most it is) and potentially degrades performance. Assuming of course you simply want to test existence of the substring.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah indeed! added to answer!thanks for attention!